# How to correctly render partial in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working on a remake of craigslist as a basic rails project. I have a login link on the homepage with an AJAX request to show a div containing the login partial.

**_login.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: { action: "/authenticate" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %><br>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.text_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit "Log In!" %>
<%= flash[:notice] %>
<% end %>
```

**categories_controller.rb** aka my homepage action methods look like this:

```
  def index
    @user = User.all
    @categories = Category.all
  end
```

I'm getting the error: "No route matches {:action=>"/users_controller/authenticate", :controller=>"categories"}"

How do I route my form to another action method in a separate controller? (i.e. users_controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Helpers**

You'll be best reading up on rails [path helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) - if set up correctly, these should point to the correct URL for you:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   collection do
      post :authenticate #-> domain.com/users/authenticate
   end
end
```

The problem you have is that you're calling `{ action: "/authentication" }` - which basically isn't an action at all. You're trying to call a *url*, which won't work.

You'll be best using the path helper as follows:

```
<%= form_for @user, user_authentication_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit your form for any particular controller, any particular action and want to pass some extra parameter (use action that define in controller that you pass on controller )

*for example*

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => {:controller => "users", :action => "authenticate"} do |f| %>
```

In the above code the form is submitted to that controller(that you pass on url) and goto that (you pass on action) action. it will take defaults to the current action.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, we have can modify it as below to get rid of the error you are getting by either by : `url: {controller: "users", action: "/authenticate" }` or using named route path for example: `{url: users_path}`.

We can pass also pass parameters like `url: {controller: "categories", action: "/authenticate", id: "SO", one: "stack" }` or `{url: users_path(id:'so')}`. These parameters are send through URL to the controller method and we can use them in controller using 
`params[:id]` or `params[:one]`.

you can see your routes using `bundle exec rake routes` or simply `rake routes`